# LibGDX + Box2D: justTouched multiplies my forces

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx, box2d

Right now my code is as follows:

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        if(cl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
            playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0, B2DVars.jumpForce, true);
        }
    }
```

It works for the most part, however if you click both mouse buttons at the same time on desktop, or multitouch on android, the jumpForce gets multiplied. I need to ignore all clicks/taps but the first until the player touches the ground again.

(cl is the contact listener.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this but in my option the best way to solve this is to limit how often a jumpForce can be applied. This will likely prevent other problems down the road.

```
//class var
float lastJumpForceTime = 0.5f; // start at 0.5f to enable jumping from the start
float jumpForceDelay = 0.5f;  // delay between jumps, 0.5f = half second


//method that calls your code
//delta time is the time since last update LibGDX provides this but you will need to pass it
public void yourMethod(float deltaTime, ...){
  lastJumpForceTime += deltaTime;  // update last jump time
  // check if player is on ground and if time since last jump is > delay
  if(cl.isPlayerOnGround() && lastJumpForceTime >= jumpForceDelay){
      lastJumpForceTime = 0.0f;
      playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0, B2DVars.jumpForce, true);
  }
}
```